# (Virtualbox) KDE Plasma glitching on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, kde

I installed that desktop environment, and when I log on, the taskbar only appears for a few seconds before completely disappearing. And, when I try to work with programs on there, they most often lock up or not move, but only the highlighting from the mouse hover works.

Also, the desktop icons will only highlight or select if the mouse is somewhere by their right.

I can't even right-click either.

My other environments are GNOME, Cinnamon, and XFCE, and XFCE is the only one of them that perfectly works on this VM.

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate to the VM?

Comment: 4 GB. I also have all 4 CPU cores enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling and disabling 2D acceleration in your VM's settings and assigning an appropriate amount of video memory (16MB absolute minimum). If your problem goes away with no acceleration, you know it's a driver issue on your host machine.

Comment: Enabling 2D acceleration is not allowed because it's only for Windows guests. I still have 3D acceleration enabled and also maximum video memory (128 MB)